# MySql Order query by value in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here is my query

```
select * from a_table where  
(19.1181753366684 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8504168987274 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
 (19.1181043770386 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8506743907928 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
 (19.1178306753238 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8506422042847 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1174454647353 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8505992889404 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1169791559797 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8505349159241 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1159857112009 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8504061698914 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1156309080473 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8503739833832 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1152862413976 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8502130508423 between minlongitude and maxlongitude)
```

I would like the resultset to be sorted in order of values i am using in where clause in between condition. 
so my result set would be in order

```
19.11817534
19.11810438
19.11783068
19.11744546
19.11697916
19.11598571
19.11563091
```

is that possible?

Thanks,
Rizwan

Comment: Are you trying to order by latitude or longitude? Just tack on ORDER BY and the column you're trying to order by at the end of your query.

Comment: minlatitude and maxlatitude are two different columns in the table?  If possible, paste the exact result that you are expecting from the table.

Comment: yes they are two different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are going to have a way to do that other than to break that down into multiple queries performed in your order of choice.

The problem is you don't have any actual field to sort on or way to associate with records in the results set were associated with with condition in the WHERE clause (they could in fact match multiple conditions).

As an alternative, you might be able to create a temp memory table of your filter data like:

```
id   latitude          longitude
1    19.1181753366684  72.8504168987274
2    19.1181043770386  72.8506743907928
...
```

An then query across a join of the tables:

```
SELECT a_table.*, temp_table.id
FROM
a_table INNER JOIN temp_table
  ON temp_table.latitude BETWEEN a_table.minlatitude AND a_table.maxlatitude
  AND temp_table.longitude BETWEEN a_table.minlongitude AND a_table.maxlongitude
ORDER BY temp_table.id ASC
```

Obviously, make sure you have indexes on all min/max lat/long fields in `a_table`.

I am not sure how you would want to handle duplicates here (may need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` on whatever the primary key is for `a_table`)

Comment: Yes, i have already done that but then again it has performance issue The above query takes 500 Miliseconds to execute for a batch of 100 whereas breaking them down in to several queries and then unioning them in order of my choice takes around 20 seconds to complete

Comment: @Rizwan Just updated answer with another option that may work for you.

Comment: thanks, had given this a try as well...but this doesn't meet the desire execution time.

Comment: @Rizwan Did you have appropriate indexes in place?  If not you might need to consider stating to tap into some of MySQL's spatial extensions to do this work properly http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: This sounds something new to me, worth a try...will let you know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use an `ORDER BY` clause to set the ordering. If your column was called latitude you would use

```
ORDER BY latitude
```

If you're generating your WHERE clause from a loop you could also use a CASE statement

```
ORDER BY CASE
  loop
    WHEN latitude = 19.11817534 THEN 1 --change the two values dynamically. 1 would be a counter
  end loop
ELSE 999 END
```

Comment: You can ORDER BY more than one item. For example you can do ORDER BY latitude, longitude. It will order by latitude and then longitude. This is good if you have several latitudes with the same value.

Comment: But the values i am using in where clause are not in any table, the query is generated on the fly in program.

Comment: The problem is I don;t think the actual lat/long values exist in the table. The table jsut has min/max values it would seem.

Comment: @Rizwan then how are the values returned using a SELECT * ? If you're not getting data from the database then what's the point of running a query?

Comment: @Shawn I'm aware you can do that, but that doesn't apply in this situation.

Comment: @MattBusche what did i miss from the question?

Comment: @Shawn that he doesn't have multiple columns to order by. He has multiple values.

Comment: @Matt I can see the columns in his query above? You order by columns so your multiple values are sorted. He says "resultset ordered"

Comment: @Matt the values i am using in where clause are generated by a program and i don't have them stored in any table as such

Comment: @Rizwan if the hard numberes are not stored thats fine. You can still order on the latitude and longitude (or any other columns you want)

Comment: @shawn ordering by lat or long doesn't solve his issue, but I think everyone understands you can do `order by latitude, longitude` it's just not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  19.1181753366684 AS lat, 72.8504168987274 AS lon, 1 AS no
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  19.1181043770386 AS lat, 72.8506743907928 AS lon, 2 AS no
        UNION ALL
        ...
        ) p
JOIN    a_table a
ON      p.lat BETWEEN a.minlatitude AND a.maxlatitude
        AND p.lon BETWEEN a.minlongitude AND a.maxlongitude
ORDER BY
        no
```

Comment: I have already tried this one, this has a performance issue...the query takes longer time to execute

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
select * from a_table where  
(19.1181753366684 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8504168987274 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1181043770386 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8506743907928 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
 (19.1178306753238 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8506422042847 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1174454647353 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8505992889404 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1169791559797 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8505349159241 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1159857112009 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8504061698914 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1156309080473 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8503739833832 between minlongitude and maxlongitude) or
(19.1152862413976 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and (72.8502130508423 between minlongitude and maxlongitude)
ORDER BY maxlatitude, minlatitude DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding how you dont have access to the table? but this is my solution:

Use PHP or whatever language you want. The easiest way to sort your result set will be to store the results in an array and order them.

```
$result = execute(select * from a_table where (19.1181753366684 between minlatitude and maxlatitude ) and ...);

asort($result);

foreach($result AS $row){
    //do what you want in here
    echo $row;
}
```